# jQuery Selector : select a box but not an element inside the box

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

Let's says I have the following code :

```
<div class="body">
  Click me and it will work.
  <div class="head">Click me and nothing will happen.</div>
</div>
```

I want to display the "it works" when you click inside the `.body` div but not inside the `.head` div. How can I do this?

With this code, the log appears even if you click on `head`:

```
<script>
$('.body').click(function(){console.log('it works !');});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event bubbling is causing your troubles.  Essentially, the event handler for your 'head' class would capture the click and then bubble that event up to your 'body' handler because there are nested.

[Here is an excellent primer on event bubbling, how it works, and how to control event bubbling.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Here is working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ADC2D/) for you to test.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.body').click(function(e){

if($(e.target).hasClass('body'))
  console.log('it works !');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called event bubbling. When you click on "head" div you also click on "body" div.

You need to add:

```
$('.head').click(function(event){event.stopPropagation()});
```

to prevent event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general solution:

```
$('.body').click(function(e){
    if(e.target === this) {
        console.log('it works !');
    }
});
```

Solved similar question on stackoverflow:
[Select only parent, exclude everything else while click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299897/select-only-parent-exclude-everything-else-while-click)